# Is it possible to return value from Rails to the client-side javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a move from a Python back end to Ruby on Rails, and some of the legacy client-side js code looks like this:

```
$http.post(url, data, config).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if(data == 0) {
            $scope.subscribed = 'true'
        } else {
            alert("There is an issue with that email address.")
            return
        }
    }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return
    });
```

I now have the back-end doing what it is supposed to do here, but unless I use the flash, I'm not sure how to return the success/failure status to the calling function. I'd like to just return an integer value so the code could continue to work as is. Is that possible? Or do I need to rewrite the front-end to use the flash hash?

EDIT: For the record, this is what the backend code that handles this looks like.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#index'

  resources :subscriptions, only: [:create]

  match '/subscribe', to: 'subscriptions#subscribe', via: :post

end
```

The controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  returnVal = -1

  def subscribe  
    begin
      # Do some stuff that could cause an exception>
      flash[:success] = "Subscribed successfully"
      logger.debug flash[:success]
      returnVal = 0
    rescue <Some exception>
      flash[:error] = "Error"
    rescue <Another exception>
      flash[:error] = "Error"
    end

    if (!flash[:error].blank?)
      logger.debug flash[:error]
    end

    render 'static_pages/index'
    return returnVal
  end
end
```

All seems to be working fine except for the "return" part.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails controllers, you don't `return` the text you want to send to the browser. Instead, you `render` it.

For example:

```
render plain: returnVal
```

(From [the Rails Guide on layouts and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-text))

Also, you probably don't need the flash hash. `flash` is for temporarily storing session data and retrieving it in the next request. Since you're only making one request here, `flash` is unnecessary.

> Or do I need to rewrite the front-end to use the flash hash?

The front-end **can't** use the flash hash. That's only accessible on the server.

> I'm not sure how to return the success/failure status to the calling function.

Your use of phrases like this makes me wonder if you really understand what's going on here. You can't directly *call* sever-side functions from the client. All you can do is make HTTP requests, just like the browser does when it visits a page. Your code just tells the browser to download a page, and the Rails backend renders the response inside that page, just like it would with any other webpage you might visit.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

You're right, I don't fully understand what's going on here (or most places for that matter ;-). I'm still very new to the Rails environment, and web app development in general. I do understand that server-side functions aren't called directly, though, but through a RESTful http request. I don't quite have my web terminology down yet. And when I said "front-end", I mean on the user-facing code (HTML) -- I understand that flash is server-side.

So do I use `render plain: returnVal` instead of the render that I have now? I'll play around with this a bit.